# No readings from compass and inclinometer

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a Samsung 700T ATIV Smart PC Pro tablet and I tried to access the different sensors using a basic Windows Store app template to test a few things out.
I used the samples from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465294.aspx

So far I was able to get data from the Accelerometer and the Gyrometer.

The Inclinometer and the Compass however are not giving me any data. I can instantiate them just fine (they are not null) using Compass.GetDefault();  and Inclinometer.GetDefault();. The "reading" event handlers are not getting invoked though.

I tried the Inclinometer and Compass samples from the SDK as well. Same result, no readings.

The tablet should be up-to-date according to the Samsung Updater tool.

Is there any other way how I can check whether these sensors are enabled and working?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Update 1:**

Using the Sensor Diagnostic Tool from the Windows Driver Kit ([Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487428.aspx)) I was able to get some more information (it's located in prog.files\Windows Kits\8.0\Tools\).

I get readings for the X, Y and Z values from the compass sensor but "Magnetic North Degrees" is always VT_NULL. Since the Runtime API is only giving me HeadingMagneticNorth and HeadingTrueNorth instead of the raw values, this may be the root of the problem. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G64nz.png)

*Now since there seems to be a working compass, I wonder what the issue might be. Driver related?*

For the inclinator, I am not getting any readings at all using the Sensor Diagnostic Tool. X, Y and Z values are VT_NULL. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gcr0D.png)

Any other Samsung Win8 tablet owners out there willing to test this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sensors work now and are providing the expected values.

The solution was to move to a different place in the house and rotate the tablet on each axis several times. This led to a re-calibration of the sensors.

It's possible that the sensor was being distracted by strong magnetic interference which prevented it from calibrating properly.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to set the reporting interval property too.